# "под Комаровом" или "под Комаровым"

Tags: склонение, грамматика

В [статье на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) используются две формы "под Комаров**ом**" и "под Комаров**ым**". Какая из них верна?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если Комаров – фамилия, то под Комаровым. Иначе (если это нас.пункт Комарово или Комаров) – под Комаровом.

Answer (score 1):

> В статье на Википедии используются две формы "под Комаровом" и "под Комаровым". Какая из них верна?

Под Ком**а**ровом. Во-первых это устоявшееся название, исторические события тенденция (сказу скажу: дурная) не склонять или склонять не по общему правилу не затронула. А во-вторых, название хоть и иностранное, но славянское, к фамилии явно не восходящее. Форма на -ым невозможна, она годится только для фамилий и редчайших притяжательных на -ов (типа "братов", "дедов", "отцов").

Касательно предложения вообще не склонять названия на -ово/-ино (во избежания, дескать, смешения со сходными названиями на -ов/- ин) - никак не могу согласится. Мало ли в русском языке омонимичных форм? Ничего, живем как-то. Для снятия омонимии есть другие приемы, использование родового слова, например: "Под поселком Комар**о**во" (под СПб).

Сложнее обстоит дело, когда название дано в чью-либо память или честь... Современные рекомендации не только допускают, но настаивают на несклонении названий типа "Пушкино". Приходится следовать, хотя мне и это не очень нравится.

(+)

Слушайте, тут еще один момент обнаружился... 
На украинском ударение падает на последний слог. И если следовать (частично) украинскому варианту, то получилось бы "битва под Комар**о**вом. Но сам этот термин - из польской историографии, советские и российские историки называют это событие иначе, не знаю про украинских. По-польски ударение должно быть (в именительном падеже) на А: Ком**а**ров. И такие названия склоняются на русском без переноса ударения (вопреки польской парадигме). Так что я все же на приведенный выше вариант: "битва под Ком**а**ровом". Но "под Комар**о**вом" во всех остальных случаях использования...
Хотя тут, конечно, есть что обсудить.  Тема явно переросла формулировку самого вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Если под Петербургом, то "под Комарово": из "под Комаровом" можно по ошибке восстановить "Комаров" (Галиция - битва при Комарове). Поэтому, несмотря на существование подобных рекомендаций, так не говорят:
http://www.gazeta.spb.ru/1563833-0/

Comment: Alex_ander, Вы бы ткнули сначала на источник по ссылке автора вопроса. Какой Петербург? Там именно о битве под Комаровом и речь.)))